# Anonymous block called via JDBC executes without error but does not run

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Probably missing something trivial here but I have a function in my Java application running on Oracle 10g which generates a bunch of insert and delete statements into a BEGIN...; END; block.

When I execute the statement, it runs without error yet the values are not inserted/deleted to the database. If I copy the SQL that is to be run into SQL developer and execute it, it works as expected.

Example SQL...

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tablea_archive (col1,col2,col3)
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM tablea;
  DELETE FROM tablea;
  INSERT INTO tableb_archive (col1,col2,col3)
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM tableb;
  DELETE FROM tableb;
END;
```

I have tried running the code via prepared,callabale and normal Statements with execute() and executeUpdate() and no joy.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Missing `commit;` maybe. In SQL Develeoper is AutoCommit on maybe.

Comment: I run the commit via the connection object after the update runs. I have also tried this with autocommit on and adding commit at the end of the block.

Comment: Never mind. I completely missread your SQL, deleting my answer.

Comment: Was this questioned answered if so mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tablea_archive (col1,col2,col3)
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM tablea;
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Inserted '||sql%rowcount||' rows');
END;
```

Your error handling should give you some form of message saying how many rows the INSERT though were being inserted. If you don't have error logging, look at [recording errors on the database end](http://blog.sydoracle.com/2011/02/using-oracles-servererror-to-catch.html)

I'd suspect either the wrong database or wrong schema.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet works. May be it can help you:

```
String  plsql = "BEGIN :myresult := dbms_random.random ; END;";
OracleDriver oracledrv = new OracleDriver();
Connection   con = oracledrv.connect(connstr, new Properties());

for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++ ) {
    CallableStatement cb = con.prepareCall(plsql);
    cb.registerOutParameter("myresult", Types.INTEGER);
    cb.execute();
    System.out.println("random ->" +cb.getInt("myresult"));
    cb.close();
}
con.close();
```

Comment: `cb.execute();` should be `cb.executeQuery();`, otherwise you'll get `java.sql.SQLException: Incorrectly set or registered parameters.`